# Strategy for wrapping multiple libraries in C++

Tags: c++, wrapper, abstraction

I have a class `Foo`, which I do not implement directly, but wrap external libraries (e.g `FooXternal1` or `FooXternal2` )
One way that I have seen to do this, is using preprocessor directives as

```
#include "config.h"
#include "foo.h"
#ifdef _FOOXTERNAL1_WRAPPER_
//implementation of class Foo using FooXternal1
#endif

#ifdef _FOOXTERNAL2_WRAPPER_
//implementation of class Foo using FooXternal2
#endif
```

and a `config.h` is used to define these preprocessor flags (`_FOOXTERNAL1_WRAPPER_` and `_FOOEXTERNAL2_WRAPPER_`).
I have the impression this is frowned upon by the C++ programmer community because it uses preprocessor directives, is hard to debug, etc. Further, it does not allow for the parallel existence of both implementations.

I thought about making `Foo` a base class and inheriting from it to allow for both implementations to exist in parallel with each other.  But I ran into two problems:

1. Pure virtual functions: `cannot instatiate an object of type 'Foo'`, which I need during use.
2. Virtual functions run the risk of running an object with no (proper) implementation.

Am I missing something? Is there a cleaner way to do this?

**EDIT :** To summarize, there are 3(.5?!) ways to doing the wrapping- 2(.5) are given by icepack, and the last by Sergey
1- Use factory methods
2- Use preprocessor directives
2.5- Use makefile or IDE to effectively do the work of the preprocessor directives
3.5- Use templates suggested by Sergay

I am working on an embedded system where resources are limited, I decided to use `template<enum = default_library>`, with template specialization. It is easy to understand for later users; at least thats what I think

Comment: As long as you are linking both external libraries, providing a virtual class and two concrete classes is a great solution -- especially if at runtime you can determine which library should be used. If you're not linking in both libraries though (or if they have namespace collisions prohibiting it) then this isn't going to work. #define / #ifdef is not always friendly but it is sometimes the best solution.

Comment: To add to mah, if you go with wrapper Foo, just declare any functions that must be overriden as pure virtual. Compiler will force you to provide implementations in concrete subclasses, once you try to instantiate the concrete subclasses.

Comment: exactly what I intended, but then I cannot instatiate Foo, since it is abstact class. Am I missing something?

Comment: Well, it sounds like you want to provide the abstract base with a factory to pick which implementation of Foo to provide dynamically, at run time?

Comment: @mah, no namespace collision, I can link both libraries. I need to instantiate Foo though

Comment: You instantiate the two subclasses of Foo: FooLibA and FooLibB, right? FooLibA and FooLibB are forced to implement any pure virtual functions you declared in Foo.

Comment: No. Foo uses either FooXternal1 OR FooXternal2. But at the abstraction level, I want to use just Foo, irrespective of the underlying implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all method names of external implementations are similar, you can use templates. Let external implementations look like:

```cpp
class FooX1
{
public:
    void Met1()
    {
        std::cout << "X1\n";
    }
};

class FooX2
{
public:
    void Met1()
    {
        std::cout << "X2\n";
    }
};
```

Then you can use several variants.

**Variant 1.** You can declare member of a template type and wrap all calls to external implementation, even with some preparations before the call. Don't forget to delete `impl` in `~Foo` destructor.

```
template<typename FooX>
class FooVariant1
{
public:
    FooVariant1()
    {
        impl=new FooX();
    }

    void Met1Wrapper()
    {
        impl->Met1();
    }
private:

    FooX *impl;
};
```

Usage:

```
FooVariant1<FooX1> bar;
bar.Met1Wrapper();
```

**Variant 2.** You can inherit from a template parameter. In this case you don't declare any members, but just call implementation's methods by their names.

```
template<typename FooX>
class FooVariant2 : public FooX
{
};
```

Usage:

```
FooVariant2<FooX1> bar;
bar.Met1();
```

A disadvantage of using templates is that there is no easy way to change implementations in runtime. But in return you get much more optimal code, because types are generated in compile-time and there is no table of virtual functions, which can make the program slower.

Comment: But you still need to have a place where you decide whether instantiate the template with `FooX1` or `FooX2` - this brings back the #ifdefs or something similar. Nice thought of using the templates, though

Comment: @Sergey It took me sometime to conTEMPLATE(!) what was happening, but that is what I am going with

Answer (score 2):

If you want the 2 implementations to coexist at runtime, interface is the way to go (for example, you can use a factory method design pattern to instantiate the concrete object, like @n.m. has suggested).

If you can decide at compilation time what is the implementation that you need, you have several options:

- Still use interface. This will allow an easy transition if in the future you'll need both implementations at runtime.
- Use preprocessor directives. There is nothing wrong here as far as C++ is considered. It's a pure design issue.
- Put the implementations in different files and configure your compiler to compile either one of them according to settings - this is actually similar to using preprocessor directives but it's cleaner and doesn't add garbage to your code (since the flags are in the solution/makefile/whatever your compiler uses).

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I'd frown upon is including both implementations in the same source file.  That might get confusing.  Otherwise, this is one of the things preprocessor flags are good at, especially if you're not linking both libraries at the same time.  It's just like supporting multiple operating systems.  Provide a consistent interface in all cases and hide the implementation details somewhere else.

Does type `Foo` need to hold any information specific to each library?  If not, you might be able to get away with this:

```
#include "Foo.h"

#if defined _FOOXTERNAL1_WRAPPER_
    #include "Foo_impl1.cpp"
#elif defined _FOOXTERNAL2_WRAPPER_
    #include "Foo_impl2.cpp"
#else
    #error "Warn about a missing define here"
#endif
```

This way you don't have to bother with virtual functions or inheritance and you still prevent any member functions from going unimplemented.

Answer (score 1):

Keep `Foo` abstract. Provide a *factory method*

```
Foo* MakeFoo();
```

that allocates a new object of either type `FooImpl1` or `FooImpl2`, and returns its address.

[Wikipedia on Factory Method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).